# What are some good learning resources for .NET Stream programming?

Tags: .net, stream

I find that whenever I need to use a Stream in .NET, I have to begin research. This usually involves finding what I can from MSDN, or stealing examples I find. Although complete, I find MSDN not sufficient for my needs to really understanding Stream usage. What is a good reference book or site for .NET Stream mastery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book ["Inside C#"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735616485)  is a little bit outdated today, but had a good chapter about the topic you are asking for.

Comment: Have Streams changed much from .NET 2.0? I can get this book for $7 on Amazon.

Comment: AFAIK they have not changed much, but other parts of the book are not up-to-date any more.